# JQuery hide/show div based on select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask-wtforms

JQuery noob here, I'm trying to make appear/disappear divs depending on multiple form select options.
My problem is that the div hide successfully, but I can't manage to make them appear back again when an option is selected.

Here is my JQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#areaFields').hide();
        $('#areaItems').hide();
        $('#areaPartners').hide();
        $('#hidden3').hide();
        $('#items').hide();
        $('#partners').hide();
        $('#fields').hide();
        $('#hidden2').hide();
        $('#block').hide();
        $('#ORDER').hide();
        $('#type').change(function () {
            $('#ORDER').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Customizing</legend>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group default1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div id="taille" class="form-group">
                                {{ form.tailleDocX.label }}
                                {{ form.tailleDocX }}
                                {{ form.tailleDocY.label }}
                                {{ form.tailleDocY }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div id="type" class="form-group">
                                {{ form.type.label }}
                                {{ form.type }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div id="customer" class="form-group">
                                {{ form.customer.label }}
                                {{ form.customer }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="ORDER" class="form-group">
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div id="block" class="form-group">
                                {{ form.block.label }}
                                {{ form.block }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="hidden2" class="form-group">
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div id="items" class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.itemsFields.label }}
                                    {{ form.itemsFields }}
                                </div>
                                <div id="partners" class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.partnersFields.label }}
                                    {{ form.partnersFields }}
                                </div>
                                <div id="fields" class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.fields.label }}
                                    {{ form.fields }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hidden3" class="form-group">
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div id="areaFields" class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.areaFields }}
                                </div>
                                <div id="areaItems" class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.areaItems }}
                                </div>
                                <div id="areaPartners" class="form-group">
                                    {{ form.areaPartners }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group default2">
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                {{ form.submit }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

To create the form I'm using WTForm from FLASK, if needed here is the code :

```
class AreaFields(FlaskForm):
    area1 = IntegerField("X0")
    area2 = IntegerField("X1")
    area3 = IntegerField("Y0")
    area4 = IntegerField("Y1")
    textArea = StringField("Texte")


class AreaItems(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name")


class AreaPartners(FlaskForm):
    area1 = IntegerField("X0")
    area2 = IntegerField("X1")
    area3 = IntegerField("Y0")
    area4 = IntegerField("Y1")
    rolePartners = SelectField("Role", id="role")


class AjouterForm(FlaskForm):
    type = SelectField("Type",
                       choices=[("INVOICE", "invoice"), ("ORDER", "order"), ("SERVICE_REQUEST", "service_request")],
                       id="type")
    block = SelectField("Block", choices=[("ITEMS", "items"), ("PARTNERS", "partners"), ("fields", "fields")],
                        id="block")
    itemsFields = SelectField("Champs", id="items")
    partnersFields = SelectField("Champs", id="partnersFields")
    fields = SelectField("Champs", id="fields")
    tailleDocX = IntegerField("Taille X", validators=[DataRequired()])
    tailleDocY = IntegerField("Taille Y", validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer = SelectField("Customer", choices=[("NotFinalData", "NotFinalData")])
    areaFields = FormField(AreaFields)
    areaItems = FormField(AreaItems)
    areaPartners = FormField(AreaPartners)
    submit = SubmitField('Voir le résumer')
```

For the moment what I want is : to hide all the div like I did, then show the div #ORDER if order is selected in the form, or to hide the div again if another option is selected, then I'll do the same for the others select and div once I can manage to make it work.

Thanks for reading !

Edit 1 : My first select that manage the first hide/show is `form.type`, it contains 3 options : INVOICE, ORDER, SERVICE_REQUEST

When I select INVOICE or SERVICE_REQUEST, everything must stay hide because thoose option aren't ready for the moment, but when I select ORDER, I wish to make appear the divs #ORDER and #block. #ORDER contains all the other divs specific to the ORDER option, #block contain another select that will make appear/disappear another div depending on the option selected.

[Here is a picture to show the actual form without being hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGrZB.png)

The first select is Type, it must make appear Block if order is selected, and block make appear a Champs depending on the option selected.

Edit 2 : BIG NEWS, I just found out what was my problem, it's so dumb of me for not seeing this at first, I used the same ID for the div and for the WTForm select... so basicly I was checking for changement for the div and not for the select... I just feel so dumb right now, thank you for trying to help me !

Comment: Your code is a little bit confusing, you might like to provide us with the *rendered* HTML so we can clearly see what's in the #type select.  You might like to have a read of [mcve] and provide a snippet that *demonstrates* the problem.  Have a close look at what the *rendered* `select` is.

Comment: Here's a working snippet that shows how this can work https://stackoverflow.com/a/59899131/2181514 - your code appears to be very similar, so it's not clear why it's not working from what you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to hide only the element your previously showed. your code should look like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var current_element = '';

        $('#areaFields').hide();
        $('#areaItems').hide();
        $('#areaPartners').hide();
        $('#hidden3').hide();
        $('#items').hide();
        $('#partners').hide();
        $('#fields').hide();
        $('#hidden2').hide();
        $('#block').hide();
        $('#ORDER').hide();
        $('#type').change(function () {

            var id = $(this).val()
            $('#' + id).show();

            // hide previously showed element
            if(current_element != '') $('#' + current_element).hide();

            // store id of previously selected element
            current_element = id
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I tried your solution, but I still can't make appear the div based on the option selected, the div has the same name as the option of the select

Comment: check the value of type selected maybe its not the same with id of the div

Comment: It's the same values, at this point I don't understand why it's not working, I followed multiple solution on different post, yet none of them work, the div wont show again, they just stay hidden :'(

Comment: can you change this $('#' + id).show() to $('#' + id).toggle() ? and this $('#' + current_element).hide() to $('#' + current_element).toggle() also;

Comment: but it successfully hide at first ?

Comment: Yup, all the divs are hidden at the start of the JQuery script

Comment: i mean on first change of type, the div successfully hide the selected type ?

Comment: Nope, it's seems like it doesn't care about the select, when I'm interacting with it, it doesn't change anything, even without the .hide() and with .toggle()

Comment: really ? what is the return of this  $(this).val() in type change ?

Comment: BIG NEWS, I just found what was my problem, it's so dumb of me for not seeing this at first, I used the same ID for the div and for the WTForm select... so basicly I was checking for changement for the div and not for the select... I just feel so dumb right now, thank you for trying to help me !

Comment: haha that's why, I hope you upvote my answer or accepted rather if this one helped you. for the effort :D

Comment: Yeah I upvoted your answer (less than 15 rep so it's not showing ^^), thanks a lot for taking your times to help a newb ! Have a good day !

Comment: Happy coding :)